# Better way to move list to csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

So I have dataframe of lists.

Here is the code for the dataframe:

```
Cafe_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'카페 URL' : URL_LIST,
                            '카페명' : CafeTitle,
                            '카테고리명' : Category_Name,
                            '글쓴이ID' : NaverID,
                            '포스트 제목' : PostTitle,
                            '포스트일' : Posting_Date,
                            '조회수' : The_Number_of_Views,
                            '비디오수' : The_Number_of_Video,
                            '그림수' : The_Number_of_Picture,
                            '댓글수' : The_Number_of_Comment,
                            '글자수' : The_Number_of_Characters,
                            '키워드수' : The_Number_of_Keyword
                           })

Cafe_dataframe.to_csv('cafe_data.csv', index=True, encoding='UTF8')

path="./cafe_data.csv"
with open(path, 'r', encoding='UTF8', errors='replace') as infile, open('cafe_data_.csv', 'w', encoding='euc-kr', errors='replace') as outfile:
inputs = csv.reader(infile)
output = csv.writer(outfile)

for index, row in enumerate(inputs):
    output.writerow(row)

os.remove('cafe_data.csv')
```

and this error is raised:

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Now, I know that `dataframe` cannot be made with *lists with different lengths*, and I checked lengths of each list, and turns out `URL_LIST` has `1000` elements while others only have `755`.

But what I need is method to create `csv` file with lists *regardless of their lengths*.

Is there any other way to create `CSV` file with list?

Or is there anyway to ignore `ValueError` and still create `pandas dataframe`?

Comment: So you want to keep `URL_LIST` to the end and fill rest of columns with nan?

Comment: @Chris That is fine. ANY method to create CSV file regardless of length of each list is fine by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `collections.OrderedDict` and `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import zip_longest

d = OrderedDict({"A": [0,1], "C": [0,1,2,4], "B": [0,1,2]})

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip_longest(*d.values())), columns = d.keys())
print(df)
     A  C    B
0  0.0  0  0.0
1  1.0  1  1.0
2  NaN  2  2.0
3  NaN  4  NaN
```

Note: `OrderedDict` is used to ensure that `d.values()` and `d.keys()` are in right order. If you are using python 3.6 or above, normal `dict` is fine.

Comment: One quick question: do it have to list all elements in d = OrderedDict({"A": [0,1], "C": [0,1,2,4], "B": [0,1,2]})? Can I simply replace that with names of the Lists?

Comment: Since you already have a `dict`, just wrap it as `d = OrderedDict(your_dict_that_is_inside_pd.DataFrame)` ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, what you are trying to convert is **not** a list. Its called `dict` of lists, where key of the `dict` is your _names_ (i.e. '카페 URL'), and values are the corresponding lists. Felt like you are in a bit of confusion with the terms.